# Libgdx, stage is creating duplicate widgets when run on android

Tags: android, user-interface, libgdx, stage, scene2d

I am trying to display a TextField on the screen. It works perfectly when the desktop version is run but when I run the android version the textfield is duplicated and the background is messed up.

[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDP7I.png)

Code of Screen class:

```
public class SetupScreen implements Screen
{
    private Stage stage;
    private Table table;

    private TextField paymentField;

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        table = new Table();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        stage.addActor(table);

        Pixmap bgPixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Format.RGBA8888);
        bgPixmap.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        bgPixmap.fill();
        Texture bgTexture = new Texture(bgPixmap);

        Pixmap cursorPixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Format.RGBA8888);
        cursorPixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        cursorPixmap.fill();
        Texture cursorTexture = new Texture(cursorPixmap);

        Pixmap selPixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Format.RGBA8888);
        selPixmap.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        selPixmap.fill();
        Texture selTexture = new Texture(selPixmap);

        TextFieldStyle textFieldStyle = new TextFieldStyle();
        textFieldStyle.background = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(bgTexture));
        textFieldStyle.cursor = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(cursorTexture));
        textFieldStyle.selection = new SpriteDrawable(new Sprite(selTexture));
        textFieldStyle.font = new BitmapFont();
        textFieldStyle.fontColor = Color.WHITE;

        paymentField = new TextField("", textFieldStyle);
        paymentField.setMessageText("Pay Rate");

        table.add(paymentField);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta)
    {
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void hide()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        stage.dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen is completely messed up because you do not clear the screen at the beginning of each frame.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}
```

Another thing to note for UI is that you should *center* your camera. Otherwise the bottom-left corner of your UI will be in the middle of your screen.

You do that with the last parameter of the `Viewport.update()` method.

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}
```

Comment: Oh man I don't know why i didn't see that before! Thank you it works now! Just because I'm curious, what causes this to be a problem when run on android but not on the desktop version?